# Docker build failed because of "port 443: Connection timed out"

Tags: git, docker, go, proxy, glide-golang

```
$ docker build buehler/twitterbeat
Sending build context to Docker daemon 96.26 kB
Step 1 : FROM golang:1.5.2
 ---> 9c67771abd78
Step 2 : MAINTAINER Christoph Buehler <christoph.buehler@bluewin.ch>
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 57cbdd07c195
Step 3 : ENV GO15VENDOREXPERIMENT 1
 ---> Using cache
 ---> fd69aeb2425d
Step 4 : RUN git clone https://github.com/Masterminds/glide.git $GOPATH/src/github.com/Masterminds/glide &&     cd $GOPATH/src/github.com/Masterminds/glide &&     make bootstrap &&     make build &&     cp ./glide /usr/bin
 ---> Running in 025c97c1cba1
Cloning into '/go/src/github.com/Masterminds/glide'...
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/Masterminds/glide.git/': Failed to connect to github.com port 443: Connection timed out
The command '/bin/sh -c git clone https://github.com/Masterminds/glide.git $GOPATH/src/github.com/Masterminds/glide &&     cd $GOPATH/src/github.com/Masterminds/glide &&     make bootstrap &&     make build &&     cp ./glide /usr/bin' returned a non-zero code: 128
```

I want to build an elastic beat (twitterbeat by buehler) with docker.
I get this error even if I set the proxies. I restarted the machine as well.
I tried everything that is in the other disucussions. (Encoding password, set proxy for git, etc.)

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you access that git link on the docker host with `curl` or `wget`? Does not sound like a docker issue and the error message is quite clear: unable to access 'https://github.com/Masterminds/glide.git/': Failed to connect to github.com.

Comment: curl: (5) Couldn't resolve proxy 'xxxxx@proxy.xxxxxx.ch'. my password is: xxxxxxxxxxxxxx@xxxxx. i think it has something to do with that "@". i changed it to %40

Comment: no it did not... @CFrei

Comment: find out why you can't reach github from the docker host. Can you ping github? Do you have a proxy issue? (I don't understand that "couldn't resolve proxy'-thing...)

Comment: The password had a "-" in it and github doesn't like "-" so I had to change the password. Percent-writing wasn't accepted. Now it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The password had a "-" in it and github doesn't like "-" so I had to change the password. Percent-writing wasn't accepted. Now it works.